# Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'https://localhost:5001/_framework/System.Private.Xml.dll'

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-5

I upgrade Blazor webassembly from .NET 5.0 RC2 to .NET `5.0.10` official, error happen

> Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for
> resource 'https://localhost:5001/_framework/System.Private.Xml.dll'
> with computed SHA-256 integrity
> 'UHUX2q+Gx7354mjjr1ud+dPsuU8BCFGrvInaRS1WmB8='. The resource has been
> blocked.

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: Rebuild, that fix it

Comment: It works! You can post your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have this issue, simply rebuild the solution to regenerate files hash.

Comment: I am bit shamed by not figuring out by myself, but what. Here is your upvote.