# "An unhandled error has occurred" at startup of Blazor WebAssembly application

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I am running a Blazor WebAssembly application hosted on ASP.NET and get that error:

```
localhost/:1 Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'https://localhost:5001/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'hl/Av7ToL1NqVw6lcR39rksbnDZRwCNcYWtAqBOsOZE='. The resource has been blocked.
localhost/:1 Unknown error occurred while trying to verify integrity.
blazor.webassembly.js:1 Error: Failed to start platform. Reason: TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at blazor.webassembly.js:1
    at blazor.webassembly.js:1
    at Object.throw (blazor.webassembly.js:1)
    at s (blazor.webassembly.js:1)
```

I have no idea what it is and what it is connected with, so I ask for help...

Comment: Does this help:[Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64990552/304683)?

Comment: [That helped.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64990552/304683) It was just necessary to rebuild the solution.

Comment: Publish all project files from "_framework" to the server.